# Primefaces Lightbox - Send post parameters to external iframe

Tags: primefaces, http-post, lightbox

I have a primefaces lightbox that opens an iframe which includes an external url. Can I send post parameters to this iframe?

My current code is:

```
<p:lightBox iframe="true">
    <h:outputLink value="http://externalURL.com/page.jsf" title="Primefaces Lightbox">
        <h:outputText value="Primefaces Lightbox"></h:outputText>
    </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
```